# Strange statement in SQL

Tags: sql

I found somewhere something like this:

```
SELECT [**] FROM [*]
```

People that are owners of this page said "*Can you compute this?*". I tried this statement in `MS SQL`, `Oracle` and `PostgreSQL` and getting an error that the syntax is incorrect.

Does anyone know what it is and what it does?

Comment: That does not work. Probably pleaceholders that get replaced by actual values somewhere before being sent to the DB

Comment: I thought the same but the question was near to some job offer for programmers. So I wanted to know if it's something like a tricky thing in SQL or just something like "you have to know selects in SQL" :P

Comment: Looks as a command for DBMS "Select something that I don't mind from somewhere which I don't know". No chances. Thus, it may be some meta-code

Comment: In SQL Server you can create columns and names which are keywords or have spaces in them. You actually use these things in SQL statements, you can surround trhem with [] - e.g. select [User] from [Silly Table Name]. It may be that there is a table called * with a column called ** - I just created one in SQL Server 2012 so it's possible. It's a damn silly idea though.

Comment: Turns out to be a pretty accurate test to see if you understand how []s work. But if I had an interview at a company where I could possibly find objects named `[*]` and `[**]` I would not be interested in working for them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This statement would work in SQL Server or MS Access or Sybase.  It is saying:  get the column named `**` from the table named `*`.

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/94a23/1) is a SQL Fiddle showing it working.

Although I can make it work, I would be really surprised if this is the actual intention of the code.

Comment: Yeah, because it's marked with the [brackets], a db object name can be basically anything, even [*]

Comment: Yup - even unicode characters. Imagine querying columns and tables named in chinese or some other non-latin alphabet... yikes!